# How do i solve these exponential equations?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Is there a way to solve these exponential equations without using logarithms?
I tried to get the same base for all the terms, but I could not make it.

Is there any other general procedure that I can use to solve them?

Thank you for your help.

$(e^x - \frac{1}{e})(e^{2x}-\sqrt{e}) = 0 $

$ 8^{x^2-2x} = \frac{1}{2}$

$10^x + 10^{x+1} = \frac{11}{10}$

Comment: Why do you want to avoid logarithms? Solving exponential equations is what logarithms _are there for_.

Comment: You can observe that $8^{-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}$ and then just compare exponents in eq. 2.

Comment: @iiivooo: That seems to be an unwanted strategy, because $-1/3$ is $\log_8 \frac 12$, and we're not supposed to use logarithms.

Comment: Comparing exponents does not **explicitly** mention logarithms.

Comment: Does it count "using logarithms" for the second if you *know* 2^3 = 8 so 8^{-3} = 1/2?  So two is simply solving 8x^2-2x=-3.  But I also must ask:  why the heck do you want t avoid ligarithms???  I think, technically you can not.  Solving exponents is, by definition, using logarithms.

Comment: Heh, heh.  Not to mention, concluding $8^{f (x)}=8^c\implies f (x)=c $ is "using logarithms" :)

Comment: These are exercises from my little brother math book. At this point he is not gone through logarithm yet, so he need to solve the equations without using them :),

Comment: @fleablood You do not need to know that logarithm exist, if you want to compare exponents. You can be just lucky/experienced enough to guess them :-)

Comment: @fleablood Can't we say that's equating parts?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question

**Hint**

You are look for values of $x$ such that the factors:
$$(e^x - \frac{1}{e})(e^{2x}-\sqrt{e}) = 0$$
That is:
$$e^x = e^{-1}, \ e^{2x} = \sqrt{e}$$

Comment: right! It was so obvious.... thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you think logorithms are that need avoiding but :

1)$(e^x - \frac{1}{e})(e^{2x}-\sqrt{e})= (e^x - e^{-1})(e^{2x} - e^{1/2} = 0$

so $e^x - e^{-1} = 0$ or $e^{2x} - e^{1/2} = 0$

So $x = -1$ or $x=1/4$

2) $8^{x^2 - 2x} = 1/2 = 2^{-1} = 8^{-1/3}$

3) $10^x + 10^{x+1} = 10^x(1 + 10) = 10^x*11 = 11/10$ so $10^x = 1/10 = 10^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one,

$$(e^x-e^{-1})(e^{2x}-e^{0.5})=0$$

$$\implies e^x-e^{-1}=0,e^{2x}-e^{0.5}=0$$

$$\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
e^x&=e^{-1} \\
e^{2x}&=e^{0.5} \\
\end{aligned} 
\right.$$

For the second one,

$$8^{x^2-2x}=\frac12$$

$$2^{2(x^2-2x)}=2^{-1}$$

For the last one,

$$10^x+10^{x+1}=\frac{11}{10}$$

$$10^x+10\cdot10^x=\dots$$

$$(1+10)10^x=\dots$$

$$11\cdot10^x=\frac{11}{10}$$

$$10^x=\frac1{10}$$

$$10^x=10^{-1}$$